# React REDUX not updating the state to the new one

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-props

Just trying to build a simple react-redux code here. Whenever I click one of the button with some data value attached to it, I just want it to use it to update state of my react app.
The directory composition is :

```
src/index.js
src/App.js
src/reduxButtonGroup.js
src/reduxActions.js
src/reducers/index.js
src/reduxStore.js
src/reduxHelloWorld.js
```

Now, coming to the codes here is how **App.js** looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './reduxHelloWorld.js';
import {store} from './reduxStore.js'
import ButtonGroup from './reduxButtonGroup.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
     <HelloWorld name = {store.getState().name} />
     <ButtonGroup names = {["NameA","NameB","NameC"]}/>
     </React.Fragment>
      )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here is how **reduxButtonGroup.js** looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import {store} from './reduxStore.js';
import {setName} from './reduxActions.js';

const ButtonGroup = ( {names} ) => (
  <div>
    {names.map((name,i) =>  (
      <Button data-name={name} key={`btn-${i}`} style={{marginRight: "15px"}} className={"btn btn-danger"} onClick={dispatchBtnAction}>
        {name}
      </Button> 
    ))}
  </div>
);

function dispatchBtnAction(e){
    const name = e.target.dataset.name;
    console.log(name);
    store.dispatch(setName(name));
}

export default ButtonGroup;
```

And **reduxActions.js**:

```
export function setName (name) {
  return {
     type: "SET_NAME",
     name: name
   }
}
```

Also, **reducers/index.js**:

```
export default (state,action) => {
    console.log(action.name)
    switch(action.type){
        case "SET_NAME":
        console.log("here")
            return{
                ...state,
                name: action.name
            };

        default:
            return state;
        }   
};
```

Here is how **reduxStore.js** looks like:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = { name: "initialName " };
export const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
```

And at last **reduxHelloWorld.js**:

```
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
            )
    }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Now, in the terminal I can see the right values in action.type and action.name . However I think that somehow the part shown below is not working. i.e., I'm unable to update my state variable called name to action.name .

```
return{
                    ...state,
                    name: action.name
                };
```

Though I'm getting the right values, my component is not getting rendered with the right values. Any idea what I'm doing wrong over here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the state in the reducer initialized to a defaultState? If it is, share the default state.

Comment: What I meant in my previous comment was, you should have something like this `export default (state=defaultState,action) => {...}`

Comment: State in store is initialised to an initialState.